# Is my cgminer (scrypt) working / Mining on middlecoin pool

Tags: litecoin, miner-configuration, cgminer, scrypt

I'm trying to mine on the middlecoin pool using the following command:

> cgminer --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://middlecoin.com:3333 -u
>   1C7Ubg5VxvJyXYBT6neNVFgUVdgq1Kiy72 -p asdf

and I do get the screen below, but I'm not seeing my bitcoin address appear on: http://www.middlecoin.com/allusers.html (and I've waited a couple of hours)

```
 cgminer version 3.7.2 - Started: [2014-01-31 13:03:27]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (5s):3.725K (avg):3.694Kh/s | A:0  R:0  HW:0  WU:3.4/m
 ST: 2  SS: 0  NB: 398  LW: 1943  GF: 0  RF: 0
 Connected to middlecoin.com diff 1.02K with stratum as user 1C7Ubg5VxvJyXYBT6ne
 Block: 1e7643a6...  Diff:1.17K  Started: [14:56:27]  Best share: 313
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [P]ool management [G]PU management [S]ettings [D]isplay options [Q]uit
 GPU 0:                | 3.703K/3.694Kh/s | A:0 R:0 HW:0 WU:3.4/m I: 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 [2014-01-31 14:51:52] Network diff set to 25
 [2014-01-31 14:51:52] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:51:56] Network diff set to 26
 [2014-01-31 14:51:56] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:52:04] Network diff set to 343
 [2014-01-31 14:52:04] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:53:46] Network diff set to 55
 [2014-01-31 14:53:46] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:54:08] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:54:32] Network diff set to 1.17K
 [2014-01-31 14:54:32] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:55:19] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
 [2014-01-31 14:56:27] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
```

---

When I exited, it showed :

```
...\cgminer-3.7.2-windows>cgminer --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://middlecoin.com:3333 -u 1C7Ubg5VxvJyXYBT6neNVFgUVdgq1Kiy72 -p asdf
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18]
Summary of runtime statistics:

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Started at [2014-01-31 13:03:27]
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Pool: stratum+tcp://middlecoin.com:3333

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Runtime: 2 hrs : 45 mins : 51 secs
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Average hashrate: 3.7 Kilohash/s
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Solved blocks: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Best share difficulty: 313
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Share submissions: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Accepted shares: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Rejected shares: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Accepted difficulty shares: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Rejected difficulty shares: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Hardware errors: 0
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Utility (accepted shares / min): 0.00/min

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Work Utility (diff1 shares solved / min): 3.53/min

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Stale submissions discarded due to new blocks: 0

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Unable to get work from server occasions: 0

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Work items generated locally: 2688
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Submitting work remotely delay occasions: 0

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] New blocks detected on network: 545

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] Summary of per device statistics:

 [2014-01-31 15:49:18] GPU0                | (5s):3.741K (avg):3.703Kh/s | A:0 R:0 HW:0 WU:3.5/m
 [2014-01-31 15:49:18]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue is that your hash rate (speed, essentially) is extremely low. You're averaging about 3Kh/s. For comparison, most mid-range miners are running around 5-600Kh/s, and if you run a mining tool on your Google Nexus 7 tablet or Nexus 4 cell phone you can get around 2Kh/s which is very close to what you're getting.

I can't really help you with this without knowing what kind of hardware you have that you're trying to run this on, but take your video card model and search google for "cgminer settings" with your model after that to see what you can find.

Comment: Hi - thanks for replying. I did use different cgminer settings and the hashrate bumped up to ~14 kH/s and I started seeing Accepts after a couple of more hours. I tried my hand at solo mining for a bit, but was completely uncertain whether it was actually working or not (different Q on BC.SE) - any thoughts on that?

Comment: The reason why I didnt see my results on the middlecoin webpage was probably related to a server issue at their end.